# unable to update Status of product from csv

Tags: csv, admin, magento-1.9, product, status

When I change the status field of product from enable to disable or vice versa via updating through csv using data flow profile, it is not updating value of status, simply leaves status of a product blank.
While manually I am able to update products as well as products status is inserted properly of new products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide a screenshot or sample of your CSV.

normally it should work if we use something like below.

sku, status
TESTSKU, ENABLED

status value will be Enabled or Disabled.